# Get iframe height

Tags: jquery, iframe

In page content i have some external iframe, the problem is that i dont want scroll to have on that iframe, but i dont know how long iframe will it be??

```
<iframe id="newsletter"
       src="http://www.vimontline.com/"
       frameborder="0"
       width="100%"
       marginheight="0"
       marginwidth="0"
       scrolling="no">
</iframe>
```

No problem with the width, the problem i have is with height, i want to remove scrool from my iframe, but i dont to make it code like height="100px", any idea with jquery how to get iframe  inside height, that i have add to my id that height?

Comment: You cannot use jQuery to access the contents of an `iframe` which has an external URL in it's `src`. In other words - this is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access this information from the parent page. If you control the URL loaded into the iframe then you're able to tell it's parent to resize once the DOM is loaded.

Code in iframe:

```
parent.resizeFrame(document.body.scrollHeight)
```

Code for parent page:

```
function resizeFrame(height) {
    document.getElementById('blogIframe').style.height = parseInt(height, 10) + "px";
}
```

You may need to add a little extra to the height to prevent scrollbar inconsistencies across browsers.

Comment: I can not control the external page?

Comment: Then you cannot achieve your goal. Sorry mate.

Answer (score 0):

iframe dynamic resizing can be achieved (cross domain) by using these scripts
[iframeResizer](http://davidjbradshaw.github.io/iframe-resizer/).

You will have to run a script on the parent page (iframeResizer.min.js) and another inside the iframe (iframeResizer.contentWindow.min.js).

It uses [postmessage api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage) and it worked for me

I hope that helps

Comment: Sadly, for this to work you will have to have control on the code of the iframe

Answer (score 0):

You can use below js code to get height of iframe

```
setTimeout(function () {
                $('iframe#newsletter').css('height', $(window).height() + 'px');
            }, 1000);
```

This solution will work for you don't need to define height it will automatically define height

Answer (score 0):

As FreeAsInBeer says, this isn't something you can really do for security purposes, just for a little more clarification see:

[Same-Origin-Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) & [Cross-Origin-Resource-Sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)

This is the closes thing I've seen to it: http://css-tricks.com/cross-domain-iframe-resizing/ but I wouldnt really recommend that either.